# Hello World C++ CUDA Program in Visual Studio 2010 (Windows 7)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, cuda

I am trying to compile this [Hello World program](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=90044) in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 installed, but I get the following error message when I run `nvcc hellocuda.cu`:

```
nvcc fatal   : nvcc cannot find a supported cl version. Only MSVC 8.0 and MSVC 9.0 are supported
```

How can I compile this CUDA program ?

Comment: Don't use Visual Studio unless you install Nvidia plugins. Visual C++ is basically a gimped version of C++, so...

Comment: I'm not directly using visual studio... nvcc is.. I have Nsight installed if thats what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#Visual_Studio_2008_Express_Downloads) was needed. (Thanks sgolodetz)

So with Visual Studio 2010 Professional (maybe 2010 Express works too?), [NVIDIA Parallel Nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html), CUDA Toolkit, Developer Drivers, and GPU Computing SDK code samples (toolkit, drivers, and sdk can be downloaded [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_toolkit_rc.html)) I was able to run the example [Hello World in CUDA](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=90044) program.

[How to create/upgrade a CUDA project in VS2008 and VS2010 to work with Nsight 1.5 and CUDA 3.2](http://developer.nvidia.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=5324) was *very* helpful in starting a new VS 2010 CUDA project with the proper settings.

Side note: I was never able to get the command line `nvcc` to work correctly, but I rather use VS 2010 IDE instead.

Update: [How do I start a new CUDA app in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046228/how-do-i-start-a-new-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2008/2047892#2047892)'s answer was also useful

Answer (score 6):

NVCC checks VC++ compiler version from Visual Studio environment variables. NVCC says it supports only MSVC 8.0 and 9.0 compilers. In your case, you have MSVC 10.0 compiler. There seems to be a workaround to this issue, check out post #7 in this thread:
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=179531 and also 
http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=88585

Answer (score 2):

If you keep having problems getting it working with MSVC10, bear in mind that you can download the Express version of MSVC9 (i.e. the 2008 version) for free -- so you can always download it and compile with that instead. But I would try swatkat's workaround first :)

Here's the link:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

Comment: Its better to download the Windows SDK and set Visual Studio to use that compiler (ought to be possible, no?)

Answer (score 0):

With CUDA 4.0 you can use the VC10 toolchain. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778799/how-do-i-start-a-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2010/7285235#7285235) for a step-by-step.