# Problem when calling template CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I've been trying to create template kernels but I'm been having some trouble calling them in my program. I have a `Matrix<T>` template class, and some methods defined inside it

Matrix.h:

```
template <typename T> class Matrix {
    ...
    void sum(Matrix<T>& m1, Matrix<T>& m2, Matrix<T>& sum);
    ...
}

#include "Matrix.cu"
```

Matrix.cu:

```
#include "MatrixKernel.h"

template<typename T> void Matrix<T>::sum(const Matrix<T>& m, Matrix<T>& sum) {
    ...
    sumKernel<T><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(Matrix<T> m1, Matrix<T> m2, Matrix<T> sum)
    ...
}
```

MatrixKernel.h:

```
template<typename T> __global__ void sumKernel(const Matrix<T> m1, const Matrix<T> m2, Matrix<T> sum) {
...
}
```

The problem is that when I call sumKernel from inside of sum, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

Does somebody know what's going on? The code compiled fine just before I included the sumKernel call.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know you could use CUDA and C++ (!). Trivial suggestion: try putting a space between the `<T>` and the `<<<` in case running them together is causing parse problems.

Comment: Did the compiler tell you which line the error is on? There's a lot of <s in cuda template code so it would be useful to narrow down which line it's on.

Comment: @Rup: yes, you can. You can even pass objects as arguments to kernels (provided you copied the data of interest to the device memory). I'll try your suggestion too.
@Bomadeno: The error is on the line that performs the kernel call.

Comment: Thanks - sounds like I'm just out-of-date. Wikipedia says the C++ support is new in CUDA 2.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it seems you do have a strange `#include`, leading to code getting compiled by the wrong compiler. Make a distinction between gpu headers and cpu headers by using .cu.h for cuda headers. Make sure *only* NVCC compiles `.cu` and `.cu.h` files. Cuda files should never be included in cpp files. The kernel and kernel call should be in a `.cu` or `.cu.h` files, and those files shouldn't be included anywhere in cpps.

Because your `.cu` is being included in a header which is being compiled by the host compiler, the host compiler ends up hitting the token `<<<` - which it doesn't recognise. It probably does understand the token `<<` so it consumes that, leaving an unexpected `<`.

Here's an alternative way of doing things that should work (not tried it but it's similar to code we use)

*(note, this might work but it also might not be the right way to solve the problem. My boss doesn't like it as a solution and would prefer to add an implementation per variation)*

The underlying problem seems to be lack of distinction between host and device code. I'm leaving the detail out in my solution - things like copying results to and from the device, sum implementation, etc.

The problem I'm trying to solve is, given a construct, how can you template it for use both on the host and the device?

I'll template `Matrix.h` on both the type and the implementation detail.

```
 template <typename T, typename Implementation<T> > class Matrix {
     void sum(Matrix<T>& m1, Matrix<T>& m2, Matrix<T>& sum)
     {
         Implementation.sumImp(m1, m2, sum);
     }
 }
```

The host implementation, `HostMatrixSum.h` will do things the on the cpu:

```
 #include "Matrix.h"

 template <typename T> struct HostMatrixSum
 {
     void sumImp(Matrix<T>& m1, Matrix<T>& m2, Matrix<T>& sum)
     {
         ...
     }
 }
```

While `GpuMatrixSum.cu.h` will upload the matrix, do the sum and recover the results:

```
 #include "Matrix.h"

 template <typename T> struct GpuMatrixSum
 {   
     template<typename T> __global__ void sumKernel(const Matrix<T> m1, const Matrix<T> m2, Matrix<T> sum)
     {
         ...
     }

     void sumImp(Matrix<T>& m1, Matrix<T>& m2, Matrix<T>& sum)
     {
         ...
         sumKernel<T> <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>> (m1,m2);
         ...
     }
 }
```

Then when we come to use Matrix from host code we template on the host sum implementation and never need to see any cuda specifics:

```
 #include "Matrix.h"
 #include "HostMatrixSum.h"

 Matrix<int, HostMatrixSum> m1 = Matrix<int>(...);
 Matrix<int, HostMatrixSum> m2 = Matrix<int>(...);
 Matrix<int, HostMatrixSum> result;
 Matrix.sum(m1,m2,result);
```

And if we're working on the gpu we can use the accelerated gpu implementation of sum:

```
 #include "Matrix.h"
 #include "GpuMatrixSum.cu.h"

 Matrix<int, GpuMatrixSum> m1 = Matrix<int>(...);
 Matrix<int, GpuMatrixSum> m2 = Matrix<int>(...);
 Matrix<int, GpuMatrixSum> result;
 Matrix.sum(m1,m2,result);
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: I'm going to try that. But at the same time it seems strange that in MatrixKernel.h, for instance, the compiler doesn't complain about the __global__ keyword (which can only mean NVCC is compiling it, right?)

Another thing: if what you say actually is the problem, where would I implement the sum method? If I don't write '#include "Matrix.cu"' inside "Matrix.h", there will be a link error, for the template must be declared and defined at the same file...

Comment: I think you were right, I had to forget about implementing Matrix as a template class, cause there was no way I could make it work that way. If I include for instance a .cu file on the header, every other file that includes the Matrix header will also include the .cu, even .cpp ones, which will inevitably give rise to a compilation error. Using template kernels is ok, but making the c++ methods that call them templates too is not possible because of what I just explained. It's a little winding after all...

Comment: Because MatrixKernel.h is only included by a cu file, only nvcc ever includes it. If you included MatrixKernel.h in a host cpp file, I suspect it would fall over. I name cuda specific headers .cu.h to clarify that it's only for inclusion from .cu files. I'm working on an answer to the 'how to do it' part of the question - trying to work out an elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: error C2059: syntax error : '<'

First, I found a good set up/tutorial here (for visual express 2010 and cuda 4.0):
http://www.stevenmarkford.com/installing-nvidia-cuda-with-visual-studio-2010/

and to solve the syntax error problem, this solved it:
[How do I start a CUDA app in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778799/how-do-i-start-a-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2010/7285235#7285235)

Specifically, changing the property of the *.cu file such that: Type is set to "CUDA C/C++"

Finally worked for me.