# Trouble working with CUSPARSE

Tags: cuda

As I wanted to compile my program (using Cusparse) the following lines appeared:

tmp/tmpxft_00001048_00000000-13_matvec.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_00001048_00000000-1_matvec.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6d5): undefined reference to`cusparseCreate'

The same came out not only for cusparseCreate, but also for cusparseCreateMatDescr, cusparseSetMatType, cusparseSetMatIndexBase, cusparseXcoo2csr, cusparseDsctr,
cusparseDcsrmv_v2, cusparseDestroyMatDescr and cusparseDestroy. What does it mean?

Comment: How are you compiling ? It looks like you are not linking against cusparse library. The answer on how to link against the library depends on the os.

Comment: How to solve same problem for windows visual studio 2010 ?

Comment: @Terminal, here's how to solve the problem with visual studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570285/how-to-link-library-e-g-cublas-cusparse-for-cuda-on-windows

Answer (score 5):

You need to link with the cuSPARSE library. Since you're using Linux, adding `-lcusparse` to your nvcc command line should be sufficient.

Note that you may also need to add the CUDA libraries path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable if the system fails to find the linked libraries when executing.

Comment: Did I miss something or is there a way you deduced that the OP was using Linux from the question he asked ?

Comment: The error message is a typical Linux error message, Windows would say something like "unresolved external symbol". I don't know what Macs say so it's possible he is using a Mac, but in that case the resolution would be the same. For Windows one would add cusparse.lib alongside cudart.lib when following these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2047892/214473 (VS2005/2008) or http://stackoverflow.com/a/7285235/214473 (VS2010).

Comment: I see those error messages in our system all the time! It is ridiculous that I couldn't notice that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, indeed I am using Linux (Ububtu). Thanks for the advice. I adedd -lcusparse and it compiled. But now, I'm facing another problem. The thing is that I want to multiply a matrix with a vector (cusparseCcsrmv) using cuComplex variables. But altough the program compiles, it doesn't return the result. With kind of objects should the vectors be? The form of the function is:

Comment: cusparseCcsrmv(cusparseHandle_t handle, cusparseOperation_t transA, int m,
int n, int nnz, const cuComplex
*alpha,
const cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, const cuComplex
*csrValA,
const int *csrRowPtrA, const int *csrColIndA,
const cuComplex
*x, const cuComplex
*beta,
cuComplex
*y)

Comment: I'm aware that y and x are vectors, but I don't know how should they be saved. Should they be saved as dense or sparse vectors?

Comment: @Terminal, here's how to solve the problem with VS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570285/how-to-link-library-e-g-cublas-cusparse-for-cuda-on-windows