# how to link library (e.g. CUBLAS, CUSPARSE) for CUDA on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, linker, cuda

I am trying to compile a cuda program which uses cusparse library. I am getting linking error:

```
kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cusparseSetMatIndexBase@8 referenced in function _main
```

And a lot of error of same kind related to cusparse library. I have included "cusparse_v2.h".
How do i link cusparse library in visual studio 2010 during compilation?

Comment: In addition to including the header file, you need to link to the library.  There are several cusparse examples in the CUDA Samples pack, such as the [conjugate gradient example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#conjugategradient), which will show you how to link to cusparse and provide a sample project with MS VS project files.

Comment: I am able to run conjugate gradient example. I have done nothing fancy this time. Build(f7) + Run(f5) and it run completely fine. How to discover that how its linking ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The general instructions for linking libraries is not specific to CUDA.  So you may want to learn more about [using MS VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114914/add-library-to-visual-studio-2008-c-project).  Anyway, the steps are like this:

1. Make sure you have opened the project that you want to work on.
2. Select View...Property Pages (from the menu)   A new dialog box will open up.
3. On the left hand side of this dialog box, select Linker to open up it's sub-menu
4. Under linker, select Input
5. Now, on the pane on the right, observe the first item which is "Additional Dependencies".  I believe `cudart.lib` should already be present there.
6. Click to the right of `cudart.lib`  You can now type in new libraries to be added.  Type a space (to separate from cudart.lib) and type `cusparse.lib`
7. Now click "Apply" in the lower right corner of the dialog box.

That *should* be all that's needed, if your project/solution file is already set up using a cuda template.  If cudart.lib is not present, or your project/solution files do not already comprehend cuda, that is a separate issue.  In that case I would recommend starting over, by cloning a project from the Samples, and building your project using that as a starting point.  It will then pick up all the proper directories to search as well as the cuda build rules.  Since all the main cuda libraries (cudart, cublas, cufft, cusparse, etc.) are all in the same location, the same search path should pick any of them up as needed.

If you wanted to link another library, such as `cublas.lib`, for example, you could follow a similar sequence, replacing `cusparse.lib` above with `cublas.lib`

Note that with newer versions of CUDA (e.g. CUDA 7.5) it will be necessary to build a 64-bit project only (follow the above steps when modifying the x64 project properties.)  CUDA 7.5 and beyond are dropping support for 32-bit projects.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by following steps:

1. Add cuda path:
   Go: "Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Libary Directories" and add $(CudaToolkitLibDir) to the list.
2. Add cuda realtime library:
   Go: "Solution Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies" and add cudart.lib to the list.
3. Add cublas library:
   Go: "Solution Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies" and add cublas.lib to the list.
4. Changing platform to x64:
   Go: "Configuration Properties->Platform" and set it to x64.
5. Run cmd.exe as administrator.
   Type in and run the following two lines of command:

**netsh winsock reset catalog**

**netsh int ip reset reset.log hit**

It may say that a reboot is required, but actually that is not necessary.
Try to debug your application again, the problem should be solved.