# Unresolved symbols linker error when trying to initialize cublas

Tags: cuda, cublas

I'm coding on VS2013 with CUDA toolkit 6.5 installed. Today I tried to use cublas. I tried different methods of initialization, and none of them was working:

1)

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas.h"
int main(){
   cublasInit();
   cublasShutdown();
}
```

2)

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
int main(){
   cublasHandle_t handle;
   cublasCreate(&handle);
   cublasDestroy(handle)
}
```

3)

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
int main(){
   cublasHandle_t handle;
   cublasCreate_v2(&handle);
   cublasDestroy_v2(handle)
}
```

All methods yield the same errors: two unresolved expressions(create and destroy). Before I used CUDA without CUBLAS and everything was working.

My GPU is NVidia GeForce 650 Ti with 3.0 compute capability.

Update. The output (for method #2):

```
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cublasCreate_v2@4 referenced in function _main
 1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cublasDestroy_v2@4 referenced in function _main
 1>C:\programs\misha\cuda\Projects\testCUBLAS\Debug\testCUBLAS.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Probably you are not linking against the cublas library.  You might want to study a [cublas sample project](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-cublas) to see how the cublas library is linked against.  And it would be helpful if you pasted the exact full output from VS into your question.  With that, it's likely that someone can definitively spot the error.

Comment: [These instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570285/how-to-link-cusparse-library-for-cuda-5-on-windows) may help.  In those instructions, use `cublas` where ever you see `cusparse`.  The output you've pasted is not the full output -- it doesn't show the compile command line, just the errors.  But it's likely you are not including cublas.lib in the link phase.  The full output including the compile command line could confirm that.

Comment: Are you linking against `cublas.lib` ?

Comment: wow! thanks a lot! Can you please explain me for the future how to find the full output?

Comment: It's in the command output pane at the bottom of the Visual studio window.  The same place where you got your `Update.  The output...`  If the `nvcc` compile command is not showing up there before the errors, then you need to change your [VS verbosity settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx).

Comment: It could also be a visual studio compiler (cl.exe) compile command, depending on how you have your project set up.  But either way it will be in the same place as where you observed the errors, with proper verbosity settings.