# cuBLAS examples, external symbol unresolved, VS2015

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I'm trying to compile and run the following code, taken from the cuBLAS guide.

```
//Example 2. Application Using C and CUBLAS: 0-based indexing 
//----------------------------------------------------------- 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#define M 6 
#define N 5 
#define IDX2C(i,j,ld) (((j)*(ld))+(i)) 

static __inline__ void modify(cublasHandle_t handle, float *m, int ldm, int n, int p, int q, float alpha, float beta) {
    cublasSscal(handle, n - p, &alpha, &m[IDX2C(p, q, ldm)], ldm); cublasSscal(handle, ldm - p, &beta, &m[IDX2C(p, q, ldm)], 1);
}

int main(void) {
    cudaError_t cudaStat;
    cublasStatus_t stat;
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    int i, j;
    float* devPtrA;
    float* a = 0;

    a = (float *)malloc(M * N * sizeof(*a));

    if (!a) {
        printf("host memory allocation failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            a[IDX2C(i, j, M)] = (float)(i * M + j + 1);
        }
    }

    cudaStat = cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtrA, M*N * sizeof(*a));
    if (cudaStat != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("device memory allocation failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf("CUBLAS initialization failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    stat = cublasSetMatrix(M, N, sizeof(*a), a, M, devPtrA, M);

    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf("data download failed");
        cudaFree(devPtrA);
        cublasDestroy(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    modify(handle, devPtrA, M, N, 1, 2, 16.0f, 12.0f);
    stat = cublasGetMatrix(M, N, sizeof(*a), devPtrA, M, a, M);

    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf("data upload failed"); cudaFree(devPtrA);
        cublasDestroy(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 

    cudaFree(devPtrA); 
    cublasDestroy(handle); 
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) { 
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) { 
            printf("%7.0f", a[IDX2C(i, j, M)]); 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 

    free(a); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting as errors some unresolved symbol, I've checked if my linker settings were fine, together with the includes. They seem to be ok, what can be the problem? My guess is that the problem is that `cublas_v2.h` include, I've tried also to change it with simple `cublas.h`, still doesn't work.

The unresolved symbols are `cublasCreate_v2,cublasDestroy_v2,cublasSetMatrix,cublasGetMatrix,cublasSscal_v2`

Comment: You have to link against the cublas library.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570285/how-to-link-library-e-g-cublas-cusparse-for-cuda-on-windows/13588857#13588857).

Comment: I thought that was already done, I realized it later.