# I'm using cusolver to perform svd but when i compile my code i get this linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

This is my code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
int main()
{
int M=1000;
int N=1000;
double *h_a=(double *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(double));
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        h_a[j*M+i]=(i+j)*(i+j);
    }
}
double *d_a;
cudaMalloc(&d_a,M*N*sizeof(double));
cudaMemcpy(d_a,h_a,M*N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
double *h_u=(double *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(double));
double *h_v=(double *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(double));
double *h_s=(double *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(double));
int work_size=0;
int *devInfo;    cudaMalloc(&devInfo,sizeof(int));
double *d_u;       cudaMalloc(&d_u,M*M*sizeof(double));
double *d_v;       cudaMalloc(&d_v,N*N*sizeof(double));
double *d_s;       cudaMalloc(&d_s,N*sizeof(double));
cusolverDnHandle_t solver_handle;
cusolverDnCreate(&solver_handle);
cusolverDnDgesvd_bufferSize(solver_handle,M,N,&work_size);
double *work;
cudaMalloc(&work,work_size*sizeof(double));
cusolverDnDgesvd(solver_handle,'N','N',M,N,d_a,M,d_s,d_u,M,d_v,N,work 
  ,work_size     ,NULL,devInfo);
int devInfo_h=0;
cudaMemcpy(&devInfo_h,devInfo,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if(devInfo_h !=0) std::cout <<"Unsucessful SVD execution";
cudaMemcpy(h_s,d_s,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(h_u,d_u,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(h_v,d_v,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
std::cout <<"Singular values\n";
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    std::cout <<"d_s["<<i<<"]="<<h_s[i]<<std::endl;
 }
std::cout <<"\nLeft Singular vectors";
for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;j<M;i++)
    {
        printf("U[%i,%i]=%f\n",i,j,h_u[j*M+i]);
}
}
std::cout <<"\nRight Singular vectors";
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        printf("V[%i,%i]=%f\n",i,j,h_v[j*N+i]);
    }
}
cusolverDnDestroy(solver_handle);
return 0;
}
```

when i compile i get these errors:
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cusolverDnDestroy@4
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cusolverDnDgesvd@64
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cusolverDnDgesvd_bufferSize@16
1>kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cusolverDnCreate@4

Comment: I can imagine those knowing cuda (not me) will want more information. E.g. what you call from your code and what parameters you send to the linker. Also did you search for calls/references in your code to those symbols ?

Comment: You'll need to add the cusolver library to your project.  The general instructions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570285/how-to-link-library-e-g-cublas-cusparse-for-cuda-on-windows/13588857#13588857).  The library you want to add is `cusolver.lib`

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue has been resolved . The linker error has been removed.