# What is the problem with my cuda fft code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, fft, cufft

I've been struggling with a simple 2d cufft example. 
Here is the instruction for my code.

1. read 4x4 matrix into 16x1 vector
2. make cufftPlan
3. do cufftMalloc, cufftMemcpy
4. execution 2d fft
5. read output data from GPU
6. show the output data

I tried to build my code on VS2010 with Cuda 8.0, but it showing this message.

```
kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cufftDestroy@4 referenced in function _main
kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cufftExecC2C@16 referenced in function _main
kernel.cu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cufftPlan2d@16 referenced in function _main
```

All header file included and 
I guess cufftHandle 'plan_input' for cufftDestroy, cufftExecC2C, cufftPlan2d is problem.
Could you guys tell me what is the problem in my code?...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cmath>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
typedef float2 Complex;

int NX, NY;

cufftHandle plan_input;
float2* ginput;
float2* goutput;

cufftResult result;
cudaError ErrorCode;

cufftComplex *idata;
cufftComplex *odata;

int main()
{
    int NX = 4;
    int NY = 4;
    int count;
    const int NUM_element = 16;

    ginput = new float2[NUM_element];
    goutput = new float2[NUM_element];

    // read File
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("array.txt");

    count = 0;
    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        inputFile >> ginput[count].x;
        ginput[count].y = 0;
        count++;
    }
    inputFile.close();


    // Main process
    //------------------------------Plan-----------------------------//
    result = cufftPlan2d(&plan_input, NX, NY, CUFFT_C2C);
    if (result != CUFFT_SUCCESS)
        return result;  

    //------------Memory Allocation for input/output-----------------//
    ErrorCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&idata, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*NY);
    if (ErrorCode != cudaSuccess){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to allocate input\n");
        return ErrorCode;   
    }

    ErrorCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&odata, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*NY);
    if (ErrorCode != cudaSuccess){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to allocate output\n");
        return ErrorCode;   
    }

    size_t sizeComplex = sizeof(cufftComplex);
    ErrorCode = cudaMemcpy(idata, (cufftComplex *)ginput, sizeComplex*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (ErrorCode != cudaSuccess){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to cudaMemcpy\n");
        return ErrorCode;
    }
    //--------------------------2-D FFT Z2Z--------------------------//
    result = cufftExecC2C(plan_input, idata, odata, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    if (result != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
        return result;      
    }


    ErrorCode = cudaMemcpy((cufftComplex *)goutput, odata, sizeComplex*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (ErrorCode != cudaSuccess){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to cudaMemcpy\n");
        return ErrorCode;
    }
    /////////////////////// destroy and free memonry ///////////////////
    ErrorCode = cudaFree(idata); 
    if( ErrorCode != cudaSuccess)
    {
        return ErrorCode;
    }

    ErrorCode = cudaFree(odata);
    if( ErrorCode != cudaSuccess)
    {
        return ErrorCode;
    }

    cufftDestroy(plan_input);

    //////////////// show result //////////////////
    for(count = 0; count < NUM_element; count++)
        cout << goutput[count].x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to link your code against the cufft library (`cufft.lib`).  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570285/how-to-link-library-e-g-cublas-cusparse-for-cuda-on-windows/13588857#13588857) are instructions, and you may wish to study a CUFFT 2D cuda sample code/project.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you. I add ('''cufft.lib'''). And also I changed config -> platform -> x64 (added from config manage).