# how to set up visual studio 2005 for cuda programming

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, gpu

I have tried to setup my visual studio environment for programming with cuda,but stil I m getting the errors as cudaMemcpy is unable to resolve..

If any of you plz help me in setting up the environment.I am coding in c++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was going to suggest this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046228/how-do-i-start-a-new-cuda-project-in-visual-studio-2008, that question is asking fro VS2008 and not VS2005. In reality the process is the same, it's only in VS2010 that the build flow has changed substantially.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047892/214473) for instructions for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 (for VS2010, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285235/214473)).

In particular, see the bit about adding the CUDA runtime library to your link dependencies.