# Use cuda function in cpp file

Tags: visual-c++, parallel-processing, cuda

How do I use CUDA function in a cpp file?

I must use a CUDA function declared in "cuda.h" (or other cuda libraries), for example `cudaMalloc`. I know it is simple to do in .cu files but my project is extended, we decide call some CUDA functions in .cpp files.

I saw in the SDK some CUDA functions are called from main.cpp, so why is it not working for me? How do I configure CUDA with Visual Studio 2010?

The error is:

> cudaMalloc identifier not found

and

> undeclared identifier                     for size_t types

Comment: have you done `#include <cuda.h>` in your header?

Comment: I've tried to clean up your question a bit to make it more readable, hopefully I understood correctly but please add more information if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call CUDA API calls from C/C++ compiled with cl.exe, just make sure you include the cuda.h header and link with cudart.lib.

For more detailed instructions on setting up Visual Studio 2010, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285235/214473).

Answer (score 1):

I created my first cuda project following this [link](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-and-cuda-easier-with-rc2/).
Also, you need to include not only `#include <cuda.h>` but also `#include<cuda_runtime.h>`.