# CUDA syntax error '<'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

in my test.cu file (cu file item type is CUDA C/C++)

```
__global__ void foo()
{
}

void CudaMain()
{

  foo<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

and in my test.cpp file

```
#include "mycuda.cu"

int main()
{

CudaMain();
return 0;

}
```

and compilator send me error "error c2059 syntax error ' <' " in test.cu file

Comment: I think it's being parsed as operator << followed by <, try adding spaces like so: foo< < < 1,1 > > >

Comment: I have no clue how does CUDA work, but in this case, you're trying to compile (#include does, actually, insert the text from the .cu file in the .cpp) the 'test.cu' file with c++ compiler, which, apparently, cannot bear the `<<<`

Comment: You should name your main test file `test_main.cu` (or something) and compile it with `nvcc`.

Comment: I try foo< < < 1,1 > > > but not working

Comment: I rename file name  from test.cu to test_main.cu but it's not working. how About CUDA rules in vs2010?

Comment: Before using CUDA, please read some documentation on both CUDA and C. You cannot compile CUDA-specific code with C++ compiler, it must be CUDA compiler (i.e. https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-llvm-compiler). C also has declarations and definitions, and are not supposed to include one source file into another unless you know what you are doing...

Comment: I'm compiling cu file with NVCC compiler :)) I'm using CUDA Driver API but in Runtime API it's not woking. :)

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in the [getting started guide for windows](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html)?  You are including a .cu file into a .cpp file, but the ms vc build rules are compiling the .cpp file with cpp build rules, not .cu build rules.  So it's tripping over the device code in a .cpp file. Rename your test.cpp to test.cu so that the device build (.cu) rules are used.

Answer (score 4):

Inclusion of CUDA source files in a C++ file doesn't work because this simply makes the CUDA source part of the C++ program code and regular C++ compilers do not understand CUDA syntax extensions. If you still want to keep your CUDA code separate from the non-CUDA C++ code, then you might want to look into separate compilation. CUDA source code can be compiled to regular object files, that can then be linked with other object files to produce an executable.

Modify the C++ code to read:

```
extern void CudaMain(void);

int main()
{
    CudaMain();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the CUDA file with `nvcc`, the C++ code with your C++ compiler and then link the resulting object files with `nvcc` (you may also need to specify the standard C++ library in the link command):

```
$ nvcc -c -o test_cuda.o test.cu
$ g++ -c -o test_cpp.o test.cpp
$ nvcc -o test.exe test_cuda.o test_cpp.o -lstdc++
```

Edit: your question is about VS2010. May be you have to create custom build steps there.

Comment: This would be applicable to the situation where c and c++ are being *linked* together.  In this case, he is *including* the .cu file into the .cpp file, not linking them together.  There are no `extern` function calls in this scenario.

Comment: Need I to copy cuda *.rules files into vs directory?

Comment: The cuda rules should already be set up properly if you followed the getting started instructions and installed cuda *after* installing ms vs.

Comment: Can somebody give me a simple runtime api kernel launching sample (+project file) .. please.

Comment: I'm doing all steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778799/how-do-i-start-a-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2010/7285235#7285235

Comment: See my comment above on your question.  Rename *all* your .cpp files to .cu

Comment: @RobertCrovella, my first suggestion was to rename the C++ file - see the 3rd comment to the OP. Still compiling CUDA and non-CUDA code separately is the better way to do it and such kind of source inclusion is a bad idea.

Comment: I want to integrate CUDA into C++ application, 
can somebody give me a simple example about this? (project file)

Comment: @GiorgiGelava try this sample: [c++ Integration](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cpp-integration)

Comment: @HristoIliev Apologies I did not understand what you were trying to communicate.  It's a sensible solution.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, no need to apologise. I had my answer completely stripped of its rationale. I've added one paragraph now to better communicate my idea.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the thread here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-build-error/52615/4

Your test file extension should be .cu as well, but if you're using MSCV rename does not enough you should create a new CUDA C/C++ source module in your VS project.

Also you should put spaces between the <> operators like.

```
foo< < <1,1> > >();
```

Because C++ cannot parse the <<<>>>.

Comment: Exactly this: **"you should create a new CUDA C/C++ source [..]"**

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was searching around and it jogged my memory for a solution that hasn't been mentioned.

The `nvcc` help offers:

```
--x {c|c++|cu}                             (-x)
        Explicitly specify the language for the input files, rather than letting
        the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix.
        Allowed values for this option:  'c','c++','cu'.
```

So although it's a bit of a blunt tool, you can do:

```
nvcc my_source.cpp -x cu ...
```

and it'll compile the `.cpp` as if it was named `.cu` (ie as CUDA).