# Can't build CUDA Test Application

Tags: testing, build, cuda, nvidia

Currently following the CUDA Getting Started guide for Microsoft Windows [ http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html ]; installed CUDA; the samples and NSight; im on Visual Studio 2010; I have checked my card and it supports CUDA. I followed the tutorials up to the demo parts... but I am getting the following error message:

====================================================================================

```
1>CudaBuild:
1>  Compiling CUDA source file bandwidthTest.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"./" -I"../../common/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile  -g   -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MTd  " -o "Win32/Debug/bandwidthTest.cu.obj" "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu" 
1>  bandwidthTest.cu
1>C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/CUDA Samples/v5.0/1_Utilities/bandwidthTest/bandwidthTest.cu(117): error : identifier "cin" is undefined
1>  
1>  1 error detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/James/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00001654_00000000-14_bandwidthTest.compute_35.cpp1.ii".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.0.targets(592,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"./" -I"../../common/inc" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile  -g   -DWIN32 -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MTd  " -o "Win32/Debug/bandwidthTest.cu.obj" "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\1_Utilities\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"" exited with code 2.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

====================================================================================

I acknowledge that cin is part of iostream which i have verified is part of my include directive in my code...

I am coming from a web developer's background; I rarely program these types...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've modified the bandwidthTest.cu file and this is not the vanilla SDK sample (since a quick check shows it doesn't use cin by default!).

You either need to use `std::cin` to explicitely state the scope or add a `using namespace std` or `using std::cin` to either the top of your file (after including iostream) or the top of the function.

Searching for info on namespaces should give more background, e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

If this isn't the problem, then post some code.

**Update**

From your it seems comment, your real question is how to create a CUDA project in VS2010. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285235/214473) for information on that! Basically you need to create `.cu` files in your project and then tell Visual Studio what to do with them (i.e. enable the build customisation).

Comment: I just commented out the cin line; what im really trying to do is to create my own CUDA project; i am unfamiliar with how VS2010 handles it. I attempted to copy the orignial bandwidthTest.cu into another project within the same solution...

1>Error: The imported project "C:\CUDA 5.0.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.