# Installing nvidia cuda template in visual studio

Tags: cuda, nvidia

[image]

I installed visual studio 2010 on my notebook , and then i installed cuda version 5.5 on my notebook . I am a beginner in parallel programming . The thing is , why am I not getting Nvidia cuda template installed in visual studio . Whenever I click on new project it shows only CLR , Win32 and General option .

How to install CUDA template in visual studio ?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html) ?

Comment: yes i followed the steps correctly , i am not able to figure out what is wrong .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I start a CUDA app in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778799/how-do-i-start-a-cuda-app-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Have you installed NSight, which is shipped with CUDA Toolkit 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7285235/214473) for getting started with VS2010. You can start with an empty C++ project, when you enable the CUDA build customisation any .cu files will be built with CUDA.